# Is there a way to take all changes from one branch during merge conflict in git?

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I am using git for version control and sourcetree as the GUI client. Recently I merged a branch into master branch and conflict occur. I am quite sure I want all changes from another branch during conflict. Do I have ways to take all changes from another branch instead of just resolve the conflicts one by one by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this thread, in order to keep the changes from the branch you are merging from, you can select the (not so intuitive) option:

```
Resolve Using Mine...
```

[image: https://answers.atlassian.com/upfiles/ResolveMine.png]